# How to use the spiderViewStatus Java API of OWASP ZAP to get the status/percentage of work done by the Spider?

Tags: java, security, owasp, zap, penetration-testing

I was following the API documentation of [Using Spider](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#using-spider). The Java based code block works great and I get an output.

- Code:

  ```
  import java.util.List;

  import org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponse;
  import org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseElement;
  import org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ApiResponseList;
  import org.zaproxy.clientapi.core.ClientApi;

  public class SpiderViewStatus {

      private static final String ZAP_ADDRESS = "localhost";
      private static final int ZAP_PORT = 8080;
      // Change to match the API key set in ZAP, or use NULL if the API key is disabled
      private static final String ZAP_API_KEY = "93tpvc1c5ek2b94arh0e7c8he";
      // The URL of the application to be tested
      private static final String TARGET = "https://public-firing-range.appspot.com";
      //private static final String TARGET = "http://localhost:3000"; //Juice Shop

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      ClientApi api = new ClientApi(ZAP_ADDRESS, ZAP_PORT, ZAP_API_KEY);

      try {
          // Start spidering the target
          System.out.println("Spidering target : " + TARGET);
          ApiResponse resp = api.spider.scan(TARGET, null, null, null, null);
          String scanID;
          int progress;

          // The scan returns a scan id to support concurrent scanning
          scanID = ((ApiResponseElement) resp).getValue();
          // Poll the status until it completes
          while (true) {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              progress = Integer.parseInt(((ApiResponseElement) api.spider.status(scanID)).getValue());
              System.out.println("Spider progress : " + progress + "%");
              if (progress >= 100) {
                  break;
              }
          }
          System.out.println("Spider completed");
          // If required post process the spider results
                List<ApiResponse> spiderResults = ((ApiResponseList)
                api.spider.results(scanID)).getItems(); for (ApiResponse
                spiderResult:spiderResults) System.out.println(spiderResult);

          // TODO: Explore the Application more with Ajax Spider or Start scanning the application for vulnerabilities

      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      }
  }
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  Spidering target : https://public-firing-range.appspot.com
  Spider progress : 0%
  Spider progress : 66%
  Spider progress : 100%
  Spider completed
  https://public-firing-range.appspot.com/sitemap.xml
  https://public-firing-range.appspot.com/robots.txt
  https://public-firing-range.appspot.com
  ```

---

Within the *View Status* section it is also mentions to execute the [status API](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#spiderviewstatus) to get the status/percentage of work done by the Spider. However when I append the code block of [spiderViewStatus](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#spiderviewstatus) :

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.out.println("Spider completed");
  // If required post process the spider results

  //spiderViewStatus: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#spiderviewstatus
  URL obj = new URL("http://zap/JSON/spider/view/status/");
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
  con.setRequestMethod("GET");
  int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
  String inputLine;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  response.append(inputLine);
  }
  in.close();
  System.out.println(response.toString());

  // TODO: Explore the Application more with Ajax Spider or Start scanning the application for vulnerabilities
  ```

I am facing `java.net.UnknownHostException: zap` as follows:

- Error stacktrace:

  ```
  Spidering target : https://public-firing-range.appspot.com
  Spider progress : 66%
  Spider progress : 100%
  Spider completed
  Exception : zap
  java.net.UnknownHostException: zap
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
      at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
      at ZAP_tests.SpiderViewStatus.main(SpiderViewStatus.java:52)
  ```

I have tried to replace `http://zap/JSON/spider/view/status/` with `http://localhost:8080/JSON/spider/view/status/` still the same error.

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

You are already calling that endpoint in your initial code using `api.spider.status(scanID)`

The `http://zap/` host only works if you are proxying through ZAP, which you don't appear to be in your second section of code.

Comment: Thanks @SimonBennetts I will take that. Is there a way we can demonstrate the usage of _spiderViewStatus_ API?

Comment: We've got java, python and curl examples here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#zap-api-spider Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Exactly @SimonBennetts I want to demonstrate the usage of this API. But I don't seem to implement it properly as a standalone script or embedding within the [Using Spider](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#using-spider) script.

Comment: You wouldnt use a ZAP standalone script to call the API - ZAP standalone scripts are already running in ZAP and can therefore access the internal classes and data structures. If you're still having problems ask on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users - thats easier for more detailed support.